# Print the memory location of an array

Tags: c, arrays

Im new to the **C** programming language. I have a pointer array with 2 elements. I want to print the values inside the array. The code I have written

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main ()
{
int *bae[] = {10,12};
int i;
for(i=0;i<2;i++) {
printf("%d",*bae[i]);
}
return 0;
}
```

When I run this code it gave me warning like:

```
warning: (near initialization for 'bae[0]') [enabled by default]
warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
warning: (near initialization for 'bae[1]') [enabled by default]
```

Hope you could help me in finding the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bae` is an array of int-pointers at the moment. If you want just an array, it should be `int bae[] = {10, 12};`

Then, you can `printf("%d", bae[i]);`

What the warning is saying ("initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast") is that you are converting `10` and `12` into `int*` when storing them in `bae`.

**EDIT**: If you *really* want to use a pointer array, then you could do something like this (though not advisable, and in no way better than my previous answer):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    int ten = 10;
    int twelve = 12;
    int *bae[] = { &ten, &twelve };
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<2;i++) {
        printf("%d",*bae[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This would now print `10` and `12`.

Comment: no i just want to print the values inside the array by the pointer like *pointer(which prints the value)

Comment: @mysqllover You don't print values inside of an array by using pointers. Well, I guess you could, but then it would be `printf("%d", *(bae+i));` That's not what you want, however.

Comment: that was exactly i wanted

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int bae[] = {10,12};
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<2; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", bae[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

produces the output:

```
10
12
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int *bae[] = {10,12};
```

It means bae is an array of integer pointers.

```
printf("%d",*bae[i]);
```

The above statement is equal to *(bae + i). so it will try to access the value at the address 10 and 11 which leads to undefined behavior.